# Check Convergence For $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\sqrt{n^2\ln(n)+5\ln(n)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\sqrt{n^2\ln(n)+5\ln(n)}}$$

we first check if $|a_n|$ converges:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2\ln(n)+5\ln(n)}}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2\ln(n)}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}$$

$p>1$ so the series in the RHS converges and so does the one in the LHS.

This is an alternating series because $-1 \leq cos(n\pi) \leq 1$ so we have to check $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and that it is decreasing.

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2*n+n^3}}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2\ln(n)+5\ln(n)}}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{{n}}=0$$

therefore the series is absolutely convergent.

Is it valid?

Comment: How do you go from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 \ln(n)}}$ to $\frac{1}{n^p}$?

Comment: @Bib-lost this is the step that I am not sure in

Comment: It's also the step that will probably break the validity of your proof, as the answer below points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$
\cos(n\pi)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if $n$ is odd};\\1&\text{if $n$ is even}.\end{cases}
$$
Hence, the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) shows that the series converges. However, the series does not converge absolutely since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln n}}=\infty
$$
(we have that $\sqrt{n^2\ln n+5\ln n}\sim n\sqrt{\ln n}$ as $n\to\infty$).

Comment: according to Wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n+from+2+to+infinity+(1)%2F(ln(n)(n%5E2%2B5)) it converges

Comment: No it doesn't. Type "sum n from 2 to infinity (1)/sqrt((ln(n)(n^2+5)))" in wolframalpha instead.

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: How do I show that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{ln(n)}}=\infty$?

Comment: @gbox We can use the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). We have that $(2\sqrt{\ln x})'=\frac1{x\sqrt{\ln x}}$.

Comment: @gbox Several questions on the site do that. Search for "condensation test" (one method amongst many).